# Cannot start SonarQube server 4.3.2 with Java jdk 1.7 for port range error

Tags: sonarqube, java-service-wrapper

I met a problem after I restarted my SonarQube server on my localhost:9000 last night, when I hit "StartSonar.bat" command, the error message showed as below.

Error message:

Unable to bind listener to any port in the range 32000-32999. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.<0x271d>

I use JDK 1.7.0_60 and my sonar server is 4.3.2 run in Windows 7 64-bit. I did some investigations on the web, the problem might occur because the port is used. I added

wrapper.port.min=32000

wrapper.port.max=32999

in my C:/[SonarQube server location]/conf/wrapper.conf
but it still doesn't work.

I don't know why it happened last night, because I could start my server well before yesterday and used it for several weeks without problems. The only reason I thought is, I did install my jre version from 7 to 8 and same with my jdk version in the past two days. But after I found this sonar error, I uninstalled them and changed my wrapper.java.command to absolute path to where jdk 1.7 version is, and confirmed it by hitting java -version on my console.

Thus, my local sonar server now using jdk 1.7 for sure. However, after solving that Java version problems, ,this Java Wrapper Service problems still keep showing up, I have no idea about this.

Anyone has the similar issues could share how you fix it?
Any helps are greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem today. I needed two services running and it seems port conflicts are not handled very gracefully. My solution that worked was to set

```
wrapper.port=31095
wrapper.port.min=31096
wrapper.port.max=31099
```

Different range of ports and different default port. Unsure which one did the trick, I would guess the `wrapper.port`

Answer (score 1):

This occurred to me a Ubuntu system after applying security updates which had been long overdue. It turned out to be caused by the loopback interface being down. This command solved it: `sudo ifconfig lo up`.

Answer (score 0):

I never had this problem so I am not sure that I can help you but something I don't understand: if you get an error in the range 32000-32999, why do you try the wrapper.port.min=32000 / wrapper.port.max=32999 range as this is the same range in error ?

Have you tried to comment these 2 lines you added after reinstalling your JKD as previously ?